# Include generated makefile without warning message

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For a project of mine I am automatically generating makefiles and including them, like this:

```
all:
    @echo 'SUCCESS is $(SUCCESS)'

clean:
    rm depend.mk

depend.mk:
    @echo 'Creating $@'
    @echo 'SUCCESS := 1' > $@

.PHONY: all clean

include depend.mk
```

This works, but the include line generates a warning message:

```
$ make
Makefile:13: depend.mk: No such file or directory
Creating depend.mk
SUCCESS is 1
```

I would like to silence that first warning line saying that depend.mk doesn't exist. I know it doesn't exist since I have a rule written to generate it, so the warning is unnecessary (unless of course there isn't a rule for it). I do NOT want make to ignore the error where the included file doesn't exist and there is no rule for it, so prefixing `include` with a `-` to ignore the error will not work for me. I'd like something similar to bash's convention of piping stderr to /dev/null like `some_cmd 2>/dev/null` but for including in make.

The sample above is a very simplified example of this case. In my actual project there are a lot of automatically generated makefiles (via clang's automatic dependency generation) being included, meaning a fresh run of `make` will flood my screen with these warning messages.

Is anything like this possible, or am I just going to have to deal with the annoying warning messages?

Comment: The clang automatic dependency files have specific rules for them? They aren't being generated as side-effects of compilation?

Comment: @EtanReisner They are pattern rules like `$(BUILDROOT)/%.d: $(CURTOP)/%.c` where the recipe is `$(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -MG -MT $@ -MT $(basename $@).o -MF $@ $<`, so they can be generated before anything is built.

Comment: Do you need to generate them before anything is built? Isn't this just wasting time? If the c file needs to be compiled, and clang can spit out both the object file and the `.d` file at the same time then why bother having it do that in two passes?

Comment: @EtanReisner That does make a lot of sense now that I think about it. I previously thought they had to be generated beforehand because otherwise the `include` would fail, but I guess there's no harm in doing `-include` so they will only be included if they've been built before. After all these rules are only used to determine if a file needs to be RE-built. In that case, should I modify the rule from `%.o: %.c` to `%.o %.d: %.c` since the recipe would be creating both files? Or would that cause all object files to be make when the Makefile is parsed (because the `include` runs the recipe)?

Comment: Read [this page](http://make.mad-scientist.net/autodep.html) for details about this idea (not my idea or site). Specifically the 'Advanced Auto-Dependencies' section.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for that. I actually modified my system to generate the dependencies during the compilation step as you suggested. My final rule now looks like this: `$(BUILDROOT)/%.o: $(CURTOP)/%.c` with the recipe: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MT $(basename $@).d -MT $(basename $@).o -c -o $@ $<`. I also ended up changing to use `-include`. This now works as I wanted it to originally. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered and (re-re-re-re-)solved this problem a number of times myself.  Really, the problem is in the thinking surrounding when the dependency files are generated and used.

This link has the detailed description of the "resolution": http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Basically it comes down to the fact that dependency files are really only necessary for rebuilding, not the initial building of your library/executable.  Resultantly you don't need to have a rule for generating dependency files up front (which is in fact less efficient), you instead should generate them during the object file step as intermediate files marked precious (so they're created and tracked as side-effect files that should never be cleaned up automatically).  Subsequent builds will then have the files available, which is exactly what you were trying to achieve overall.  You can then make it a "-include" on the dependency files, with the foreknowledge that your object file build step will fail if the dependency file generation fails, giving an immediate error, as you've mentioned is preferred, rather than an obscure and indirect one much later.

I've actually done a couple rather large build systems implementing this method, and it does work quite well, including ones that used non-GNU toolchains.  To an outside user it appears identical, but internally it performs more efficiently and isn't hiding potentially important errors.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many (many!) things to see if I could prevent or redirect the error message.  No luck.

But when I tried `-include` (include with a leading dash), it didn't give an error, and `make` with `clean`, `all`, `depend.mk` and 'default' all worked properly and as expected.

Is there a particular reason you didn't want to use the `-include` variant?  Seems to do exactly what you're looking for, and doesn't alter how the Makefile works in any way, just doesn't show the error during the first pass through the Makefile.

Comment: The issue with using `-include` is that if some of the dependency files fail to generate for some reason then there is no error message displayed. This causes issues down the line such as hard to diagnose broken builds or not automatically updating built products without resorting to a `make clean`. I do want `make` to yell at me if it tries to include a file that has no build rule.

Comment: But considering your Makefile rules, depend.mk is unconditionally made, so it should always be available. The `-include` __ONLY__ suppresses an error on a non-existent file.  Any garbage in the file will cause errors as expected.  You should add logic to verify `depend.mk` was correctly created to the tail of the commands creating `depend.mk`.  There is no other place at which it would be logical to test its existence or content.  Make executes the commands, if they fail, (and you don't prefix cmds with '-'), then the Make process will fail.

Comment: Please understand that the sample makefile I provided is a much simpler version of what I'm actually using (close to 1000 lines of makefile code in total). There are tons of dependency files being generated automatically from different places with different flags, paths, and patterns. Some are generated from `$(eval`ed function calls that occur when including the makefiles of subdirectories (as this is a non-recursive make build system, as mentioned in the "Recursive Make Considered Harmful" paper). I did try the `-include` first, but I had issues with hard to diagnose errors, so I changed it.

Comment: Fair enough.  But if your dependency creation logic isn't robust or doesn't at least [_fail-fast_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast), you're going to have issues, as you've discovered.  Worst case, it's just an annoying output message, and my inner OCD whines about it too, I'm feeding her chocolate to calm her down.  {Sigh} We tried.  Good Luck.

Comment: `-include depend.nk` is the way to go, together with a rule to build `depend.mk`. If this is giving inconsistent results, it's because your `depend.mk` rule is broken. Remember that on error, the recipe should _not_ create a `depend.mk` file, and it should exit with an error.

Comment: FWIW I use `include $(wildcard ${dependfiles})`, but that's because I am sure this is what I want. YMMV

Comment: @bobbogo My build rule is actually a pattern rule like `$(BUILDROOT)/%.d: $(CURTOP)/%.c` where the recipe consists of `$(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -MG -MT $@ -MT $(basename $@).o -MF $@ $<` to have clang automatically generate a dependency file if there is a corresponding C source file (CPP is defined as clang -E). The problem is that if this errors, the file isn't created, but make carries on perfectly happy because it was told to ignore errors (because of the `-include`), unless I'm getting mixed up some how.

Comment: In this scenario it is an error if the `.d` file cannot be created. `-include` is wrong in this circumstance. You will just have to put up with the creation of all `.d`  files on first the first run of _make_. Naturally, this isn't a very good setup.

Comment: @C0deH4cker You should remove your pattern rule for `.d` files and use the `-MMD` flag instead.