# How to include makefile dynamically

Tags: c++, dynamic, makefile, include

Now I have two makefiles, A.mk and B.mk.

A.mk will include B.mk
But B.mk is dynamically generated by some command which is executed in A.mk

Here is the pseudo code of A.mk

```
command to generate B.mk 
include B.mk
compile and link
```

The question is the include command is something like #include macro in C file. the A.mk try to load the B.mk before the command is executed.

Does anyone can give me some advise?

Many Thanks
Jerry

Comment: You might change to cmake. Quite powerful but it takes some time to get the grip on it.

Comment: This Q/A may help also: [SO: Makefile target dependency to generated files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37738434/7478597).

Comment: The hint with `-include` in @TimF 's answer can be found here also: [SO: Include generated makefile without warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24774588/7478597).

Comment: psuedo-code isn't really helpful.  "command to generate B.mk" could mean almost anything, and the devil is in the details.  What you want is a MCVE, then show the invocation of make, the results you got, and explain why those results weren't what you wanted.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to make it work like this:

**a.mk** (at this point, `b.mk` doesn't exist)

```
-include b.mk

all:
    @echo foo : $(FOO)

b.mk:
    @echo "FOO=2" > b.mk
```

With `make -f a.mk all` we obtain this :

> foo : 2

The sign `-` in front of the include directive allows not to generate a warning if `b.mk` doesn't exist.

As stated by [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) in the comments, you don't need to put `B.mk` as prerequisite of any target. If `make` sees it's missing and finds a corresponding target it will automatically build it.

Comment: You don't need to make `b.mk` a prerequisite of `all` (or any other target).  Make will always try to build all included makefiles even if they're not prerequisites of anything.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html

Comment: Using `include` doesn't throw an error, just a warning.  It still works.  Also, the use of `-include` is no longer necessary if you have GNU make 4.2 or above; make is smart enough now to avoid giving an error until it's sure that the makefile doesn't exist _and_ that it can't be rebuilt.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for those information, I didn't know that. I've updated my answer. Concerning `make` 4.2+ I'm not sure I got it and cannot test it now but do you mean that the warning doesn't appear if `B.mk` doesn't exist but can be built ?

Comment: Correct.  (you can run `make --version` to see which version you have)